# Unable to fetch a public variable from a class from a swift framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode9, swift4

I have developed an iOS framework. I integrated it in a project using cocoapods and everything was ok. Now I used carthage and I am able to import it and access the public classes. But now I am not able to get the public variables which was taking place earlier when I used cocoapods. "No visible @interface for 'PublicHelperClass' declares the selector 'publicVariable'" is the error I am getting while accessing the variable. The framework is written in swift and the file I am importing the framework in is in objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My header file did not contain all the methods and public variables hence I was unable to access it.

Another method which helped me to get the resources out of the framework was to follow the method of using getBundleIdentifier to get the name of the bundle which had the stuff.